# Showing that the power is $P=UI$ using the Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, power, poynting-vector

If I have a circuit with a resistor I want to show that the power delivered to the resistor is UI using Poynting vector. To do this I must integrate the pointing vector over a surface that contains the resistor. If A is the surface I must find:

$\int \int\limits_A \frac{1}{\mu_0}(E\times B)\cdot (-n) dA$.

How can I show that this expression is UI?(U=voltage, I=current) The biggest challenge I have is that I do not know which direction the electric field is pointing.

I suspect that we should end up with $\int E\cdot dr I$, where we integrate the electric field over a line over the resistor.

Comment: Recall Poynting's theorem, assume uniform $\mathbf E,\mathbf j$, assume $\mathbf E$ is conservative field, rewrite $\int \mathbf j \cdot \mathbf E dV$ as $\int \mathbf j \cdot d\mathbf S \int \mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf x$ and see that one integral is current $I$, the other is potential difference $U$.

Comment: @JánLalinský Thank you. I am just wondering about something: when you say uniform E, do you mean that the field E is the same strength around the resistor?, can the field E change radially outwards?. Do we also assume that E is parallell to the resistor?

Comment: In reality resistors have complicated shape and composition, so electric field is not uniform. But in the simplest possible case, we can assume resistor which has electric field uniform inside.

Answer (score 1):

This derivation is paraphrased from the [MIT Electromagnetics 6.013 online textbook](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/book.html) section 13.3. It is actually easier to prove it for a more general case than specifically for a resistor.

We assume that

1. around the circuit device (lumped element) there exists an imaginary Gaussian surface such that over that surface the electroquasistatic assumption is valid
2. the contribution of the displacement current is negligible on the surface
3. there are a finite number of small discrete "ports" where current goes in or out of the Gaussian surface.

From the electroquasistatic assumption (assumption 1) we have $$\vec E = - \nabla \phi$$ and from the definition of the Poynting vector, evaluated over the surface defined above we have the total power going in through that surface is $$P=-\oint \vec S \cdot d\vec a= -\oint \vec E \times \vec H \cdot d\vec a = \oint \nabla \phi \times \vec H \cdot d\vec a$$ Then there is a vector identity that lets us rewrite the right hand side as $$=\oint \nabla \times (\phi \vec H)\cdot d\vec a - \oint \phi \nabla \times \vec H \cdot d\vec a$$The first term is 0 because the curl of a vector has no divergence and the surface integral of a divergence-free field is 0. We can use Ampere's law to rewrite the second term as $$=\oint \phi \left(\vec J + \frac{\partial \vec D}{\partial t}\right)\cdot d\vec a$$

Now, from assumption 2 we have $\partial \vec D/\partial t \approx 0$ so $$=\oint \phi \vec J \cdot d \vec a$$

Finally, from assumption 3 the integral becomes a discrete sum $$=\sum_i \phi_i (\vec J_i \cdot \vec a_i) = \sum_i \phi_i I_i$$

So as long as the assumptions are met on any Gaussian surface around the circuit element, regardless of what happens inside that surface, then we get the total power is equal to $P=UI$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have one question: In the last step do you assume that the potential is constant over the "port"?

Comment: Yes. I added “small” to the description to help convey that concept. It is only the potential that actually needs to be constant over the port.

Comment: Is there missing a minus after you use Ampere's law?

Comment: You say: "The first term is 0 because the curl of a vector has no divergence and the surface integral of a divergence-free field is 0." Do you use the divergence theorem here? If so is that a problem since we assume that the potential function does noe exist inside the lumped elements? So we can't integrate over all inside the Gaussian surface?